# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am using `Oracle.sql.ARRAY` inside my code, for which I had to use `ojbc6.jar`.

When I use `ojdbc6.jar` as scope(provided),I get `ClassNotFoundException` and when I use scope as runtime I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`.

How do I resolve this issue?Is there any alternative for oracle.sql.ARRAY?

Comment: you seem to have two conflicting drivers. Where is your app running?

Comment: jboss eap,Yes, I dont want to keep ojdbc6 jar inside my lib folder,but oracle.sql.ARRAY needs the jar at runtime.

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/205386

Comment: Is there any jdbc driver installed on jboss eap as core module? Did you add any jdbc driver to jboss eap? The jdbc driver should not be in your app, but you should add it to your AS.

Comment: Yes,jdbc is installed on jboss eap.